# Enviar valor JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

Les pido su ayuda para resolver un problema que tengo, que creo puede ser muy simple la solución, ya que no me manejo muy bien con JavaScript.

En mi sistema implementé DATATABLES a una lista que tengo, esto funciona bien y no tengo problemas. En mi sistema los usuarios pertenecen a una carrera en especifico y dependiendo de esto en cada lista se muestran solicitudes para cada carrera.

Anteriormente a implementar DATATABLES, utilizaba **$car = $_SESSION['carrera'];** para obtener la carrera del perfil que se logueaba y con eso realizaba las validaciones en la lista.

Código de pagina de lista:

```
 <?php 
   session_start();
   include "../conexion.php";
 ?>

  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section id="container">        
      <div class="table-responsive-sm">
       <table id="mydatatable" style="width:100%">  
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>FECHA</th>
                        <th>FECHA INICIO</th>
                        <th>FECHA TERMINO</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>  
            </table>
        </div>      
 </section>
 </body>
 </html>
```

El código para el DATATABLE es el siguiente:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
     listar();
  });
  var listar = function()
  {
     *** $car = $_SESSION['carrera'] ***
     var table = $('#mydatatable').DataTable( 
     {
        ajax:
        {    
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            orderCellTop: true,
            fixedHeader: true,
            *** url:'consultas/sqlLista.php?id=<?php echo $car; ?>', ***
            method:'POST'
        },
        columns:
        [
            {"data":"id"},
            {"data":"fecha"},
            {"data":"inicio"},
            {"data":"termino"}
        ],
        order: [
        [0, 'desc']
        ],
        language: {
        url: "https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.19/i18n/Spanish.json"
      },
      });
   }
   </script>
```

En la url coloco la ruta en donde esta el archivo con la consulta que trae la información que muestro en la lista:

```
***ARCHIVO sqlLista.php***

 <?php
   session_start();
   include "conexion.php";  

   $car = $_REQUEST['id'];

   $query = mysqli_query($conection,"SELECT id, fecha, inicio, termino
   FROM servicio
   WHERE estado = 1 and id_carrera = $car");

   $result = mysqli_num_rows($query);
   if($result > 0)
   {
      while($DATA = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
      {
        $ARREGLO["data"][] = $DATA;
      }
      echo json_encode($ARREGLO);
   }
   mysqli_free_result($query);
  ?>
```

En definitiva, lo que necesito es pasarle a la consulta un parámetro con el valor de la carrera, esto lo intenté enviándolo a través de url, pero no logra enviar el valor. Y si lo hago ingresando un valor directamente si lo hace.

```
 NO ENVIA VALOR:  url:'consultas/sqlLista.php?id=<?php echo $car; ?>'

 SI ENVIA VALOR:  url:'consultas/sqlLista.php?id=1'
```

Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar a resolver esto. Gracias.

Comment: Si es una variable de sesión de php, por qué no simplemente la llamas en tu sqlLista.php y ya? tratas de enviar una variable del backend al frontend para luego volver a pasarla al backend ¿?

Comment: Lo intenté, cargue la variable de sesión directamente y tampoco me funcionó.

Comment: En `sqlLista.php` sólo debería de ser  `$car = $_SESSION['carrera'];` en vez de `$car = $_REQUEST['id'];` y listo. Si no tiene valor `$car` , entonces debes de revisar donde estás seteando esa variable de sesión

Comment: La variable sesión la utilizo en varias paginas de mi sistema, pero en sqlLista.php no logro que funcione correctamente, es por eso que busco otra alternativa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No se te envía el valor porque no puedes incrustar así código PHP en JavaScript, pues responden de diferente manera y orden.

Lo que se me ocurre que podrías hacer es crear un elemento y extraer el valor de sus atributos con JQuery para que lo puedas utilizar dentro de tu función.

**MÉTODO 1 - Usar `input hidden`**

Creamos en tu archivo de estructura un `input` oculto y le asignamos el valor que necesitas, en este caso lo tienes en una variable de sesión.

```
<table id="mydatatable">
    <input type="hidden" id="carrera" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['carrera']; ?>">
</table>
```

Con Jquery simplemente lo extraes en una variable para que la puedas utilizar:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
     listar();
  });
  var listar = function()
  {
     var id_carrera = $("#carrera").val();
     var table = $('#mydatatable').DataTable( 
     {
        ajax:
        {    
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            orderCellTop: true,
            fixedHeader: true,
            url:'consultas/sqlLista.php?id='+id_carrera,
            method:'POST'
        },
        columns:
        [
            {"data":"id"},
            {"data":"fecha"},
            {"data":"inicio"},
            {"data":"termino"}
        ],
        order: [
        [0, 'desc']
        ],
        language: {
        url: "https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.19/i18n/Spanish.json"
      },
      });
   }
   </script>
```

**MÉTODO 2 - Usar Data attributes**

En un elemento que ya tengas creado, añadimos un data attribute con el valor que deseas.

```
<table id="mydatatable" data-carrera="<?php echo $_SESSION['carrera']; ?>">
</table>
```

Después en tu JQuery sólo lo llamas utilizando

```
var id_carrera = $("#mydatatable").data("carrera");
```

Finalmente, concatenas la variable en tu `url` como en el método anterior.

```
url:'consultas/sqlLista.php?id='+id_carrera,
```

Comment: Te agradezco tu respuesta, Intente con ambos métodos pero sin éxito. En el caso del Método 2 realice validaciones y observo que no logra capturar el valor de sesión, ya que si paso directamente un valor a var id_carrera = 1; si logra cargar correctamente.

Comment: @SBK22 ¿No será que `$_SESSION['carrera'];` no está definido? ¿Puedes comprobar qué imprime eso en PHP? ¿Cuál es el valor de data-carrera que te imprime? ¿Podemos ver en qué parte tienes definidas tus variables de sesión?, quizá ese es el problema.

Comment: Lo acabo de solucionar, era un problema con la consulta que venia vacía. Pero me funcionó con el método 2. Muchas gracias.